# How can I add different plural endings of time units such as seconds, minutes and days?

Tags: php, time

I need help/advice on adding a bit of functionality to a piece of php code that manages a "time ago"-function. Basically it compares post date to current time. It all works fine when using English, as all plurals (second**s**, minute**s**, hour**s**, day**s**, year**s**) end with the letter `s`.

```
if( $time_difference < 1 ) { return 'less than 1 second ago'; }
$condition = array( 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 =>  'year',
            30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'month',
            24 * 60 * 60            =>  'day',
            60 * 60                 =>  'hour',
            60                      =>  'minute',
            1                       =>  'second'
);

foreach( $condition as $secs => $str )
{
    $d = $time_difference / $secs;

    if( $d >= 1 )
    {
        $t = round( $d );
        return 'about ' . $t . ' ' . $str . ( $t > 1 ? 's' : '' ) . ' ago';
    }
}

}
?>
```

In my native language however, this is not the case. So I need advice on how to set different endings depending on what amount has elapsed.

For example (keeping it pseudo foreign so it'll be understandable) I'd like to specify them as:

```
1 second / 2 secondFoo
1 hour / 2 hourBar
1 day / 2 dayRick
1 month / 2 monthRoll
1 year / 2 yearYeah
```

I could probably just use an if-statement, but I'm having trouble differentiating between second, minute, hour, etc. when doing so. Also, there's probably a much more clever way to do this that I haven't thought about out there.

Comment: Why not just make the original array a multidimensional array containing both singular and plural forms (something like this `array(1=>['second','seconds'])`) and then in the return you put `return "about {$t} ".($t > 1 ? $str[1] : $str[0])." ago";`

Comment: Ah, yes! Clever and effective – works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rolling this functionality yourself you could try using a library like [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon). It includes all of the functionality you need to create human readable times and dates (http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff) but also contains localisation functionality (http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization).

Answer (score 0):

```
function plural($n, $f1, $f3, $f5)
{
    return $n%10==1&&$n%100!=11?$f1:
        ($n%10>=2&&$n%10<=4&&($n%100<10||$n%100>=20)?$f3:$f5);
}

echo plural($number, 'day', 'days', 'days'); // 2 forms (english)
echo plural($number, 'день', 'дня', 'дней'); // 3 forms sequence (order $f5, $f1, $f3): 0, 1, 2-4, >=5, 21, 22-24, >=25, 31, 32-34, >=35... (russian)
```

Yes, you must convert seconds to days or months number for correct plural.
What your native language? You can tune this function for you language and plural forms.